# JAVASCRIPT unable to assign variables got from FIRESTORE - solved: few nested promises

Tags: javascript, database, google-cloud-firestore

new to Firestore. tried to be as clear as possible. cannot assign attributes received from firsetore DB,
could not find an answer in js.

building a q&a forum, have 3 collections : users, message, query.
trying to add a query (after creating valid documents of msg and user and have their doc id).
when printing to console, works fine but does not update db

when had the same problem with numbers, tried to wrap with parseInt and it worked, but parseString doesn't seem to exist.
also tried only declaring the variables without assaining " ", but then got an error.

```
function DBaddNewQuery2(userID, firstMsgId) {
  let creatorFirstName =" ";
  let creatorLastName=" " ;
  let firstMsgText =" ";

  // get the user's first and last name
  db.collection("users").doc(userID).get().then(function(doc) {
    creatorFirstName = doc.data().firstName;
    creatorLastName= doc.data().lastName;
    console.log("creatorFirstName is ",creatorFirstName); // prints the right data!
    }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting first and last name for user in addquery2:", error);
  });

  // get msg text
  db.collection("message").doc(firstMsgId).get().then(function(doc) {
    firstMsgText = doc.data().msgText;
    console.log("msg text is ",firstMsgText); // prints the right data!
    }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });

  // generate query id
  let queryId = create_UUID();

  db.collection("query").doc(queryId).set({

    'creatorFirstName': creatorFirstName, //update db as " "
    'creatorLastName': creatorLastName,
    'firstMsgText': firstMsgText,

  }).then(function () {
    console.log("setDocument: query Document successfully written!, query id: ", queryId);
  })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("setDocument: Error writing document: ", error);
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a bunch of asynchronous functions in a row, where subsequent functions rely on data from previous functions?

Comment: yes, i'm sorry if that was not clear

Answer (score 1):

1- async/await can do some trick here

```
    async function DBaddNewQuery2(userID, firstMsgId) {
      let creatorFirstName = ' ';
      let creatorLastName = ' ';
      let firstMsgText = ' ';

      // get the user's first and last name
      let userRef = await db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userID)
        .get();

      creatorFirstName = userRef.data().firstName;
      creatorLastName = userRef.data().lastName;
      // get msg text
      let messageRef = await db
        .collection('message')
        .doc(firstMsgId)
        .get();

      firstMsgText = messageRef.data().msgText;

      // generate query id
      let queryId = create_UUID();

      db.collection('query')
        .doc(queryId)
        .set({
          creatorFirstName: creatorFirstName, //update db as " "
          creatorLastName: creatorLastName,
          firstMsgText: firstMsgText,
        })
        .then(function() {
          console.log(
            'setDocument: query Document successfully written!, query id: ',
            queryId,
          );
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error('setDocument: Error writing document: ', error);
        });
    }
```

2- Nested structure

```
function DBaddNewQuery2(userID, firstMsgId) {
  let creatorFirstName = ' ';
  let creatorLastName = ' ';
  let firstMsgText = ' ';

  // get the user's first and last name
  db.collection('users')
    .doc(userID)
    .get()
    .then(function(doc1) {
      creatorFirstName = doc1.data().firstName;
      creatorLastName = doc1.data().lastName;
      console.log('creatorFirstName is ', creatorFirstName); // prints the right data!

      // get msg text
      db.collection('message')
        .doc(firstMsgId)
        .get()
        .then(function(doc2) {
          firstMsgText = doc2.data().msgText;
          console.log('msg text is ', firstMsgText); // prints the right data!

          // generate query id
          let queryId = create_UUID();

          db.collection('query')
            .doc(queryId)
            .set({
              creatorFirstName: creatorFirstName, //update db as " "
              creatorLastName: creatorLastName,
              firstMsgText: firstMsgText,
            })
            .then(function() {
              console.log(
                'setDocument: query Document successfully written!, query id: ',
                queryId,
              );
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.error('setDocument: Error writing document: ', error);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('Error getting document:', error);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(
        'Error getting first and last name for user in addquery2:',
        error,
      );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me,  not only nested like @MUHAMMADILYAS kindly suggested, but also with Promise.all

thank you!

```
function DBaddNewQuery(userID, firstMsgId) {

  let creatorFirstName = " "; let creatorLastName = " "; let firstMsgText = " ";
  // generate query id
  let queryId = create_UUID();

  var userRef = db.collection("users").doc(userID);
  const promise1 = userRef.get();
  const promise2 = db.collection("message").doc(firstMsgId).get();
  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then((values) => {
    doc1 = values[0];
    doc2 = values[1];
    creatorFirstName = doc1.data().firstName;
    creatorLastName = doc1.data().lastName;
    firstMsgText = doc2.data().msgText;

    db.collection("query").doc(queryId).set({  // CREATE QUERY:

      'creatorFirstName': creatorFirstName, 
      'creatorLastName': creatorLastName,  
      'firstMsgText': firstMsgText,  
    }).then(function () {
      console.log("setDocument: query Document successfully written!");
    })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("setDocument: Error writing document: ", error);
    });

  });

  return queryId;
}
```